# mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50630 Library:100027

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 202

Backtrace:

File: /home/clientname/public_html/application/controllers/Main.php
Line: 14
Function: __construct

File: /home/clientname/public_html/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

i receive this kind of error which yesterday is not showing. i didn't even change my code even the codeigniter system code.

i tried to change my config with this code

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

and put this database (based on codeigniter user guide)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

but still it appears the problem
what would be the possible reason for that and what is the solution?

Comment: Your code might be the same, but SOMETHING has updated either PHP or MySQL, so now your driver files are for a different version.

Comment: so it means the problem is with my hosting server?

Comment: If what you described is true, then yes.

Comment: @PaulD yes its all true coz im done with my system and this friday will be the turnover to our client. since yesterday no error like that. but when i checked a while ago i just saw that error. so i think i need to contact the hosting regarding that matter. thanks for the answer

Comment: What I meant was not to imply you were not telling the truth, but that sometimes changes are implemented by mistake, deleting something, overwriting something, someone else with access doing something even apparently minor. Good luck with it BTW,

Comment: @PaulD oh im sorry i misunderstood your reply. I've already sent a message to hosting i think they made some changes without my knowledge, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read an old code and dont want change thing that is working
this is a work around :

in system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
line 202

surround the mysqli->real_connect
with

```
$err_level = error_reporting(E_ERROR);
// code containing mysqli->real_connect
error_reporting($err_level);
```

this is a a lower error reporting level
that show error and dont show Warning

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might have been fixed, but I am putting a workaround for the next visitors. Your code may be same but somehow either some php driver or mysql server/client version might have been updated and so it won't work now. I faced the same issue and found out that removing php-mysql(`rpm -e --nodeps php-mysql`) and installing the native driver php-mysqlnd(`yum install php-mysqlnd`) fixes the issue. Don't forget to restart httpd(`service httpd restart`). Try this!

N.B: I am assuming you are root user, if not add sudo(if you have sudo permission :P and if don't have that too, ask your admin).